# OAuth2 redirect_url_mismatch error in oauth playground

Tags: google-apps-script, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, gmail-addons

[image]
I have created the Credentials and configured my Gmail Addon to use the same.

I am Using the : https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2 in the Gmail Addon (I am not using the messages's temp access token).

I have generated an "Auth Code" from the Gmail Add-on application (without creating access tokens from the same). I now want to use the same to generate the access token from Auth Playground [I finally want to use the Authorization Code for another Java application to pull in users emails]

I wanted to check if the same Authorization Code can be used by OAuth Playground

**Using "Authorization Code" from the Gmail Addon in the OAuth2 Playground always gives: redirect_url_mismatch error.**

```
code=4%2FAABqS_YGEwyFBM4N42-NzRMaOU6kGis2VWgvcv9tbiP77zBjJWzM096oO04rJ26uXOQDKEpyYvElb2kp1Jzd7gU&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=183587298757-6pm37j05msctfimobq0kl48fsap42v7i.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=yGhUgj-vZDuxyz-2Hrmb7EHE&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code


HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Content-length: 75
X-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
X-content-type-options: nosniff
Transfer-encoding: chunked
Expires: Tue, 06 Mar 2018 15:54:51 GMT
Vary: Origin, X-Origin
Server: GSE
-content-encoding: gzip
Cache-control: private, max-age=0
Date: Tue, 06 Mar 2018 15:54:51 GMT
X-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
Alt-svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303338; quic=51303337; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,38,37,35"
Content-type: application/json; charset=UTF-8
{
  "error_description": "Bad Request", 
  **"error": "redirect_uri_mismatch"**
}
```

I have reconfirmed that I have the : https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground listed under "Authorized redirect URIs" I have tried with and without slash both.

I have correctly used "Use your own OAuth credentials" and put in the Client Id and Secret. The same ones used by the Gmail Addon to create the auth tokens.

Firstly, is it possible to achive what I am trying to do ? If so what is it that I am missing out on thats leading to this error ?

I might be missing something, but I have not been able to pinpoint it.

I have read the other answers with similar questions and have had no success in getting this to work.

[image]

The Code to setup the client (The credentials are same that I used in the playgound, store in properties) :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just add the  `/oauth2callback` at the end in your Authorized redirect URIs which looks like:

```
https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/oauth2callback
```

Comment: what's the error this time? can you screenshot your whole Google Developer Console credential part which is related to this?